# How do I use a generic type within a generic class declaration?

Tags: c#, generics

The following code...

```
class Repository<T> where T : Func<TIn, TOut>
{
//...
}
```

causes VS to complain that "the type or namespace name 'TIn'/'TOut' could not be found."

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can't constrain a type `T` to `Func<Tin, TOut>` because you canonly constrain types to interfaces, non-sealed classes or types.

Comment: Func<T, T1> is a type

Comment: @Kenneth Sorry, should have said "type parameter" not just "type"

Comment: What semantics do you want here? You want one `Repository` type per 2-tuple of arbitrary other types? Then you need `Repository<TIn, TOut>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Func` itself was a generic class, then yes you could via:

```
class Repository<T, TIn, TOut> where T: Func<TIn, TOut>
```

However, you couldn't do this with `Func` as it can only be constrained by an interface/non-sealed class or a type parameter.

As an alternative, you could pass the `Func` in as a constructor argument and it *would* work i.e.

```
class Repository<TIn, TOut>
{
    public Repository(Func<TIn, TOut> func)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Not really sure if that would give you what you're after though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the type you want, there's no need to put a constraint on it.
I think what you want is this:

```
class Repository<TIn, TOut>
{
    public void someMethod(Func<TIn, TOut> func)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the "inputs" for `TIn` and `TOut` in the definition of your class, otherwise, the compiler doesn't figure out from where took that

```
class Repository<T, TIn, TOut> where T : Func<TIn, TOut>
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't constrain a type `T` to Func because you can only constrain types to interfaces, non-sealed classes or type parameters.

If you *could* do it, it would look like this:

```
class Repository<T, TIn, Tout> where T: Func<TIn, TOut>
{
    //...
}
```

But you're not allowed to constrain to `Func<>`, so the whole thing is doomed.

The error message from the compiler is:

> Error  1   'System.Func' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.